# PyTest suite level GUID

Tags: python, concurrency, pytest, mutex, guid

I am a programmer working with a pytest suite using xdist - we execute it like this

```
python -m pytest -n 4
```

So it will run 4 workers - each of which is blind to each other

We had need of a global mutex object which we accomplished using an external lock file

But there were unexpected errors when we discovered that the lock file was being shared across runs!

I invented a hacky solution (nevermind that)

Every **good** solution I could think of requires processes have a shared, execution specific identifier (GUID), OR alternatively a way to execute one piece of code only one time before the suite starts

I'm hoping there's some obvious solution I've overlooked. Presumably, this is a common issue.

Comment: The lockfile is based on this example here https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/ but tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp().parent was returning the same path between different executions :(     If tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp().parent returned a different directory for each suite execution, it would have been, perhaps not a true guid, but at least a system level unique identifier that could have accomplished the same goal

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: What can I use as a unique identifier of a specific suite execution, shared between (ie available to) all worker processes?

Comment: Use `tmp_path` fixture instead of `tmp_path_factory` (or, if you insist on the factory, `tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp()`, without getting the parent). The temp dir is created new for each test session.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a UUID in the master process and pass it to the worker nodes using the custom `pytest_configure_node` hookimpl.

Comment: pytest-xdist has added a globally available testrun guid

it's called testrun-uid available as of version 1.32